# Can I use the getCasketContents method for any casketID?

Tags: node.js, api, steam, steam-web-api

I was taking a look at the following module.

https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-globaloffensive

Does anyone know if the method getCasketContents can be used for any casketID or just for the casketIDs of the "caskets" you own in your own inventory?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The code in [index.js](https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-globaloffensive/blob/master/index.js) has a comment near the end of `GlobalOffensive.prototype.getCasketContents` that says

> // This is our casket, and it's the correct notification

Before that it registers a handler for if the request times out and testing that the response is the correct value and is some special Steam-specific type.

After the comment it clears the timeout, removes an event handler, calls the callback it is sent, and adds the previously removed event handler back again before finishing.

So, it looks like it can be called with any `casketId` but won't work unless the casket is owned by the user.